# "AssertionError: Gaps in blk ref_locs" - Python - Pandas - Multithreading - 2 dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, multithreading

```
import pandas as pd
import threading as th

def foo():
  t = True

  while (1):
    if (t):
      df1.loc[1, ["A", "B", "C"]] = df2.loc[0, ["A", "B", "C"]]
    else:
      df1.loc[0, ["A", "B", "C"]] = df2.loc[1, ["A", "B", "C"]]

    t = not t


df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3, "a"], [4, 5, 6, "b"]], columns = ["A", "B", "C", "D"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]], columns = ["A", "B", "C"])

th.Thread(target = foo).start()
th.Thread(target = foo).start()
```

Unfortunately, I cannot show the whole code but I tried to represent the critical section. There are more instructions which access the dataframes. If i delete the instructions `df1.loc[1, ["A", "B", "C"]] = df2.loc[0, ["A", "B", "C"]]` and `df1.loc[0, ["A", "B", "C"]] = df2.loc[1, ["A", "B", "C"]]`, the output is correct (considering that other instructions modify the remaining columns not listed here).
Does anyone know the meaning of the error message and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing the exact same issue in the same (if not similar) scenario.

In my main script, I instantiate a single unique thread:

```py
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        marketing_th = FY22_Marketing(df=dataset, line=line, event=main_th_event)
        marketing_th.start()
        marketing_th.join()
```

The `run()` method of the class `FY22_Marketing` spawns as many threads as there are strings in `FY22_Marketing.PLAY_FIELDS`. Each sub-thread are child of `PlayCrawler` thread class:

```
def run(self):
    for playname in FY22_Marketing.PLAY_FIELDS:  # List of strings
        worker = PlayCrawler(queue=self.queue, event=self.event, name=playname)
        worker.daemon = True
        worker.start()

        self.workers.append(worker)

    # Spawn Thread as many as play they are
    for i in range(len(FY22_Marketing.PLAY_FIELDS)):
        playname = FY22_Marketing.PLAY_FIELDS[i]
        funct_nm = FY22_Marketing.MAP_PLAY_MTH[playname]

        self.queue.put((self.df, globals()[funct_nm], playname))

    # Wait the thread until all items is consumed.
    self.queue.join()

    return self.df
```

Where the `PlayCrawler` is a `threading.Thread` child, whose run method looks like:

```
def run():
    while True:
        # Get the work from the queue and expand the n-ple
        df, function, play = self.queue.get()

        try:
            if self.event.is_set():
                function(df, event=self.event)
        except Exception as e:
            self.exception = e
            with open(f'generated/[log] {self.name}.txt', 'a') as f:
                f.write(str(e))
                f.write(traceback.format_exc())
        finally:
            self.queue.task_done()
```

each `Crawler` saves its own exception stack trace in a separated files (if exists).

The `globals()[funct_nm]` from the main function `run()` is for passing the name of the function (for example `play2()`). Actually we have 5 functions, starting from `play1()` up to `play5()`. The sample `play2()` method and the rest of the methods looks similar to the following:

```
def play2(df, event: threading.Event = None):
    if not event.is_set():
        return

    core_org_status = df['Core Org Status']
    dato_segm_num = df['Datorama Segment (Numeric)'].replace(np.nan, 0).astype(int).values
    adve_stud_segm_num = df['Advertising Studio Segment (Numeric)'].replace(np.nan, 0).astype(int).values
    dato_ord_qty = df['Datorama Order Qty'].replace(np.nan, 0).astype(int).values
    adve_stud_ord_qty = df['Advertising Studio Order Quantity'].replace(np.nan, 0).astype(int).values
    mast_carv = df['Master Carve']
    acc_inte_acc_inte_name = df['Account Intelligence: Account Intelligence Name']
    acc_deta_look_acc_deta_name = df['Account Detail Lookup: Account Details Name']

    mclist = ["AMER CAN CMRCL MID", "AMER CAN ENTR", "AMER CAN SMB GRB", ...]
    acvlist = pd.Series([45013.75, 112351.33, 27685.99, ...])  # Has same # of elements than `mclist`

    play_cond = ((acc_inte_acc_inte_name != "") & (acc_deta_look_acc_deta_name != "")) & ((core_org_status == "ACTIVE") & (dato_segm_num >= 4) & (adve_stud_segm_num >= 4) & (dato_ord_qty == 0) & (adve_stud_ord_qty == 0))

    df["FY22-Mktg Data-Driven Advertising"] = "No"
    df.loc[play_cond, 'FY22-Mktg Data-Driven Advertising'] = 'Yes'

    df['FY22-Mktg Data-Driven Advertising ACV'] = 0
    mc_cond = mast_carv.isin(mclist)
    play_qualified = df.loc[play_cond]
    mc_qualified = play_qualified.loc[mc_cond]
    acvs = acvlist.take(mc_qualified['Master Carve'].apply(lambda x: mclist.index(x.strip())))
    acvs.index = mc_qualified.index
    df.loc[play_cond, "FY22-Mktg Data-Driven Advertising ACV"] = 67800
    df.loc[play_cond & mc_cond, "FY22-Mktg Data-Driven Advertising ACV"] = acvs
```

This is basically for adding two new columns, one is flag-like (contains just `yes` or `no`) and the second is a calculated value ($$$).

Each function `play1, 2, 3...` adds two new columns into the dataset, performing a similar calculation: filter the rows with `vectorization` then creates new columns and assigns the calculated values.

When we run the code, we observed a weird behavior: Sometimes one or more than one `crawler` thread(s) raise(s) an exception, all regarding to `AssertionError: Gaps in blk ref_locs` or `AssertionError: Number of manager items must equal union of block items`. Sometimes it runs all the thread without any issue.

The CSV file contains approximately 3.4M of rows.

Here how it looks like the different exceptions raised randomly from any of the 5 threads:

```
Gaps in blk ref_locsTraceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/dmin/Git/oracle-sqls/PlacematFY22_Marketing.py", line 96, in run
    function(df, event=self.event)
File "/Users/dmin/Git/oracle-sqls/PlacematFY22_Marketing.py", line 129, in play1
    q = df.loc[play_cond]
File "/Users/dmin/Git/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 894, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
File "/Users/dmin/Git/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1103, in _getitem_axis
    return self._getbool_axis(key, axis=axis)
File "/Users/dmin/Git/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 913, in _getbool_axis
    return self.obj._take_with_is_copy(inds, axis=axis)
File "/Users/dmin/Git/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3597, in _take_with_is_copy
    result = self.take(indices=indices, axis=axis)
File "/Users/dmin/Git/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3583, in take
    new_data = self._mgr.take(
File "/Users/dmin/Git/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 1474, in take
    return self.reindex_indexer(
File "/Users/dmin/Git/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 1297, in reindex_indexer
    self._consolidate_inplace()
File "/Users/dmin/Git/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 996, in _consolidate_inplace
    self._rebuild_blknos_and_blklocs()
File "/Users/dmin/Git/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 248, in _rebuild_blknos_and_blklocs
    raise AssertionError("Gaps in blk ref_locs")
AssertionError: Gaps in blk ref_locs
```

```py
Number of manager items must equal union of block items
# manager items: 26, # tot_items: 27Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/dmin/Git/oracle-sqls/PlacematFY22_Marketing.py", line 93, in run
        function(df, event=self.event)
    File "/Users/dmin/Git/oracle-sqls/PlacematFY22_Marketing.py", line 126, in play1
        q = df.loc[play_cond]
    File "/Users/dmin/Git/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 895, in __getitem__
        return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
    File "/Users/dmin/Git/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1104, in _getitem_axis
        return self._getbool_axis(key, axis=axis)
    File "/Users/dmin/Git/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 914, in _getbool_axis
        return self.obj._take_with_is_copy(inds, axis=axis)
    File "/Users/dmin/Git/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3600, in _take_with_is_copy
        result = self.take(indices=indices, axis=axis)
    File "/Users/dmin/Git/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3584, in take
        self._consolidate_inplace()
    File "/Users/dmin/Git/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5541, in _consolidate_inplace
        self._protect_consolidate(f)
    File "/Users/dmin/Git/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5529, in _protect_consolidate
        result = f()
    File "/Users/dmin/Git/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5539, in f
        self._mgr = self._mgr.consolidate()
    File "/Users/dmin/Git/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 986, in consolidate
        bm = type(self)(self.blocks, self.axes)
    File "/Users/dmin/Git/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 143, in __init__
        self._verify_integrity()
    File "/Users/dmin/Git/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 325, in _verify_integrity
        raise AssertionError(
AssertionError: Number of manager items must equal union of block items
# manager items: 26, # tot_items: 27
```

```py
Number of manager items must equal union of block items
# manager items: 27, # tot_items: 28Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/dmin/Git/oracle-sqls/PlacematFY22_Marketing.py", line 93, in run
        function(df, event=self.event)
    File "/Users/dmin/Git/oracle-sqls/PlacematFY22_Marketing.py", line 158, in play2
        play_qualified = df.loc[play_cond]
    File "/Users/dmin/Git/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 895, in __getitem__
        return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
    File "/Users/dmin/Git/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1104, in _getitem_axis
        return self._getbool_axis(key, axis=axis)
    File "/Users/dmin/Git/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 914, in _getbool_axis
        return self.obj._take_with_is_copy(inds, axis=axis)
    File "/Users/dmin/Git/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3600, in _take_with_is_copy
        result = self.take(indices=indices, axis=axis)
    File "/Users/dmin/Git/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3584, in take
        self._consolidate_inplace()
    File "/Users/dmin/Git/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5541, in _consolidate_inplace
        self._protect_consolidate(f)
    File "/Users/dmin/Git/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5529, in _protect_consolidate
        result = f()
    File "/Users/dmin/Git/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5539, in f
        self._mgr = self._mgr.consolidate()
    File "/Users/dmin/Git/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 986, in consolidate
        bm = type(self)(self.blocks, self.axes)
    File "/Users/dmin/Git/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 143, in __init__
        self._verify_integrity()
    File "/Users/dmin/Git/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 325, in _verify_integrity
        raise AssertionError(
AssertionError: Number of manager items must equal union of block items
# manager items: 27, # tot_items: 28
```

```py
Number of manager items must equal union of block items
# manager items: 28, # tot_items: 29Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/dmin/Git/oracle-sqls/PlacematFY22_Marketing.py", line 93, in run
        function(df, event=self.event)
    File "/Users/dmin/Git/oracle-sqls/PlacematFY22_Marketing.py", line 212, in play4
        play_qualified = df.loc[play_cond]
    File "/Users/dmin/Git/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 895, in __getitem__
        return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
    File "/Users/dmin/Git/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1104, in _getitem_axis
        return self._getbool_axis(key, axis=axis)
    File "/Users/dmin/Git/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 914, in _getbool_axis
        return self.obj._take_with_is_copy(inds, axis=axis)
    File "/Users/dmin/Git/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3600, in _take_with_is_copy
        result = self.take(indices=indices, axis=axis)
    File "/Users/dmin/Git/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3584, in take
        self._consolidate_inplace()
    File "/Users/dmin/Git/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5541, in _consolidate_inplace
        self._protect_consolidate(f)
    File "/Users/dmin/Git/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5529, in _protect_consolidate
        result = f()
    File "/Users/dmin/Git/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5539, in f
        self._mgr = self._mgr.consolidate()
    File "/Users/dmin/Git/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 986, in consolidate
        bm = type(self)(self.blocks, self.axes)
    File "/Users/dmin/Git/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 143, in __init__
        self._verify_integrity()
    File "/Users/dmin/Git/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 325, in _verify_integrity
        raise AssertionError(
AssertionError: Number of manager items must equal union of block items
# manager items: 28, # tot_items: 29
```

And wanted to know what the error is due to but in google there is no enough blogs/stack-overflow-cases.

If someone had a similar issue and figured out the reason, we both will appreciate it a lot.